# How to represent XML levels in a Dataset with DataTables in .NET

Tags: .net, xml, datatable, dataset

This may be a silly question but I need to do the following in .NET:

I have an XML document like this:

```
<I_WOs>
  <I_WO>
    <I_WO_HEADER><External_Source_Id>1</External_Source_Id></I_WO_HEADER>
    <I_WO_PART><Part_Number>1</Part_Number></I_WO_PART>
  </I_WO>
  <I_WO>
    <I_WO_HEADER><External_Source_Id>2</External_Source_Id></I_WO_HEADER>
    <I_WO_PART><Part_Number>2</Part_Number></I_WO_PART>
  </I_WO>
</I_WOs>
```

Now I need to programatically build this in .NET using a Dataset and DataTables.
Note: the I_WO_HEADER tag and the I_WO_PART tags both contain many more fields (columns in the datatable). I have simplified it here.

So far I have this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("I_WOs");

DataTable workorderTable = new DataTable("I_WO");
DataTable headerTable = new DataTable("I_WO_HEADER");
DataTable partTable = new DataTable("I_WO_PART");

ds.Tables.Add(workorderTable);
ds.Tables.Add(headerTable);
ds.Tables.Add(partTable);
```

But the part I don't understand is how to link the datatables so that the Header and Part are UNDER I_WO, and not siblings?

If I do ds.GetXml() then it does not look the same.
If I load the XML into the dataset then I can see that it has 3 tables, like the ones I have defined above.

Any help please?

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you need DataSets and DataTables? There are likely to be simpler approaches. (Also tell us which version of .NET you're using.)

Comment: Hi Jon, I am using a dataset which is passed in as XML to a SQL stored proc - it currently has a file poll which grabs XML (like the one above) and loads it into a dataset then uses .GetXml to pass it to SQL). I now have the data from another souce and need to replicate the dataset - changing the method at this stage is not an option (although I would love to hear more efficient methods). I am using C# 3.0). Thanks

Comment: It's now unclear whether you're trying to build a *DataSet* or XML. In the question you talk about creating XML from a DataSet, but in that comment you talk about replicating the DataSet...

Comment: Ok, so I am given 4 datatables; I now need to loop through them and build a new dataset which, when I call GetXml(), gives me the above XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you do this with the relationship of tables, if you have FK constraints between tables either XML designer of VS or ReadXML will show/return properly nested structure.

Rodney the point from your XML fragment above is that yes, `I_WO_HEADER` and `I_WO_PART` are inside the `I_WO` node but since `I_WO` node has no its own attributes there would be no way to create such FK to create the hierarchy.

in fact from what I can see, I_WO table is empty and could not exist and only the two other tables have fields.

this from a quick look, can you try to model your data in DataSet designer in Visual Studio than from the code you create an instance of the class, add some data like the values above to the columns and export to disk calling WriteXML so you see what exactly you receive?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me a bit - I read this article - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515990/converting-dataset-into-xml-with-nested-elements and I set up datarelations between the tables and it looked a lot better. However, I had to duplicate a table to get the empty I_WO node - see the code below

Answer (score 0):

I found some links that took me a bit further:
[Converting DataSet into XML with nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515990/converting-dataset-into-xml-with-nested-elements)
and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sfkwf9s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#Y400

So I setup some keys on the ID data like this:

DataRelation headerPartRelation = workOrderDetailsDataSet.Relations.Add("HeaderPart", workOrderDetailsDataSet.Tables[0].Columns["EXTERNAL_SOURCE_ID"], workOrderDetailsDataSet.Tables[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515990/converting-dataset-into-xml-with-nested-elements).Columns["EXTERNAL_SOURCE_ID"]);
        headerPartRelation.Nested = true;
        headerPartRelation.RelationName = "HeaderPart";

```
    DataRelation headerLabourRelation = workOrderDetailsDataSet.Relations.Add("HeaderLabour", workOrderDetailsDataSet.Tables[0].Columns["EXTERNAL_SOURCE_ID"], workOrderDetailsDataSet.Tables[2].Columns["EXTERNAL_SOURCE_ID"]);
    headerLabourRelation.Nested = true;
    headerLabourRelation.RelationName = "HeaderLabour";

    DataRelation headerMiscRelation = workOrderDetailsDataSet.Relations.Add("HeaderMisc", workOrderDetailsDataSet.Tables[0].Columns["EXTERNAL_SOURCE_ID"], workOrderDetailsDataSet.Tables[3].Columns["EXTERNAL_SOURCE_ID"]);
    headerMiscRelation.Nested = true;
    headerMiscRelation.RelationName = "HeaderMisc";
```

However, the problem still remains on how to get the empty I_WO tag. I copied the Header table and renamed it to I_WO and imported all the rows from it and set a datarelation. This gave me the structure I needed, BUT the I_WO tag has duplicate header elements in it now! I am not sure how to avoid this.

As Jon pointed out - I need to think what I am trying to achieve here - I need the XML in that format and I have 4 data tables with the data.

The other option is to serialize it to XML by hand instead of using .GetXML. I could then build up the tags I need and loop through the datatables as required. I am not sure of the best way of doing this...